# Find Product ID with the most “average stock” by month MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find the average stock by month which is calculated as `Total stock in a month/ total date in a month`.

This is what I got so far.

The `product_history` table example:

```
new_log_date               id      stock
2018-10-30 00:00:00        1001    59      
2018-10-30 00:00:00        1002    35     
2018-10-30 00:00:00        1003    54      
2018-10-30 00:00:00        1004    40     
2018-10-30 00:00:00        1005    5      
2018-10-30 00:00:00        1006    20     
2018-10-30 00:00:00        1007    69     
...
```

You can create a table with this [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4NcfYGUhNvPHW7NrcJ91HX/3). This code contains 5 months (May-Oct) and 2 `product_id`: `1001` and `1002`.

This is my code:

```
SELECT month(new_log_date), product_id, sum(stock) as "Total stock in a month"
FROM product_history
group by month(new_log_date), product_id
```

Output:

```
month(new_log_date) product_id Total stock in a month
10                  1001       1681
10                  1002       1273
10                  1003       1541
10                  1004       1550
...
```

How can I get the average by month like the equation?

**Update:**

I just replace the `CREATE` and `INSERT` code with `db-fiddle` link for you guys.

Comment: @Strawberry I just update my post with the `db-fiddle` link. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: Please provide the corresponding desired result (and perhaps consider whether your data set is minimal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think you would want `avg()`:

```
select month(new_log_date), product_id,
       avg(stock) as avg_stock
from product_history
group by month(new_log_date), product_id;
```

But I suspect you really want to treat days with no rows as `0`.  If so:

```
select month(new_log_date), product_id,
       sum(stock) / day(last_day(min(new_log_date)) as avg_stock
from product_history
group by month(new_log_date), product_id;
```

Note:  If you are extracting the month, you should be including the year as well.